# jq: exclude object with specified key

Tags: jq

Input:

```
{
    "name":"JSON",
    "good":true,
    "target":"yes"
}
{
    "name":"XML",
    "good":false
}
```

I would like to exclude object WITHOUT key "target", as follow but NOT has:

```
jq -r ".| select(has(\"target\"))"
```

expected output:

```
{
    "name":"XML",
    "good":false
}
```

tried this:

```
jq -r " . | del(select(has(\"target\")))"
```

but there are two returned objects, one of them NULL

```
null
{
  "good": false,
  "name": "XML"
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Select those who do *not* have `target`; that way, you do not use `del`:

```
jq -r 'select(has("target") | not)'
```